# Error: Expected associated type but found enum. I'm getting this error even after defining the associated type as a custom enum in the mock runtime

Tags: benchmarking, custom-types

I'm trying to run the following benchmark test:

```
use primitives::{CurrencyId, TokenId};

benchmarks! {
    onboard_asset {
        let caller: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();
        let currency_id: CurrencyId = CurrencyId::NativeToken(TokenId::GasToken);
        let enabled: bool = true;
    }: _(RawOrigin::Root, currency_id.clone(), enabled.clone())
    verify {
        assert_eq!(FeeAssets::<T>::get(currency_id), Some(enabled));
    }
```

but am getting this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> pallets/fee-enablement/src/benchmarking.rs:14:24
   |
9  | / benchmarks! {
10 | |     onboard_asset {
11 | |         let caller: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();
12 | |         let currency_id: CurrencyId = CurrencyId::NativeToken(TokenId::GasToken);
13 | |         let enabled: bool = true;
14 | |     }: _(RawOrigin::Root, currency_id.clone(), enabled.clone())
   | |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found enum `CurrencyId`
...  |
36 | |     impl_benchmark_test_suite!(FeeEnablement, crate::mock::ExtBuilder::default().build(), crate::mock::Runtime);
37 | | }
   | |_- arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::MultiCurrency as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::CurrencyId`
                         found enum `CurrencyId`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::MultiCurrency as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::CurrencyId` to `CurrencyId` or calling a method that returns `<<T as pallet::Config>::MultiCurrency as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::CurrencyId`
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
note: associated function defined here
  --> pallets/fee-enablement/src/lib.rs:77:10
   |
74 |        #[pallet::call]
   |   _______________-
   |  |_______________|
   | ||
75 | ||     impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
76 | ||         #[pallet::weight(1000]
77 | ||         pub fn onboard_asset(
   | ||                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
78 | ||             origin: OriginFor<T>,
79 | ||             asset_id: CurrencyOf<T, T::MultiCurrency>,
   | ||____________-
80 | |              enabled: bool,
   | |_____________-
```

The associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::MultiCurrency as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::CurrencyId` is declared to be the enum `CurrencyId`in the mock runtime definition.

The same function accepts `CurrencyId` enum as input parameter when I run it in unit tests, but throws this mismatched types error for benchmark tests. Please help me fix this error. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `where_clause` to your benchmarks which allows to enforce that associated types from the pallet's config are some particular concrete types.

I believe something along this lines should work for your case:

```rust
benchmarks! {
    where_clause {
        where
            T: pallet::Config,
            T::MultiCurrency: orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>,
            T::MultiCurrency::CurrencyId: CurrencyId,
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using the `where_clause` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the `CurrencyId` to the associated type.

I'm not familiar with your code.

But here is a simple example.

Note, these are pseudo codes.

```rust
trait Currency {
    type Balance: From<u128>;
}
type Balance = Currency::Balance;
fn mint(origin, balance: Balance) {}


benchmarks! {
    let amount: Balance = 100_u128.into();
    mint(someone, amount);
}
```

Although, we config the `Balance = u128` in mock/runtime.

You can not use `u128` directly, you need to convert it to the `Balance` associated type.

Just like you can not use `CurrencyId` directly, you need to convert it to the `CurrencyOf<T, T::MultiCurrency>`.

Comment: You *actually can* use `u128` directly in benchmarks, if you add an appropriate `where_clause`. Take a look a [this code](https://github.com/Wiezzel/substrate-dex/blob/203dd718020232439c26b4acefd1ceac0cbc99fd/src/benchmarking.rs#L25-L27).